# Typescript - Why are objects with optional values still optional in if check?

Tags: typescript, object, if-statement

I saw this at work recently and I was wondering why Typescript doesn't understand the code below. If test is either undefined or a string, shouldn't it understand that it has to be a string if it's in an if statement?

```
interface IObj {
  test?: string;
}

const obj: IObj = {
  test: "why does this not work?",
};

if (obj.test) {
  const { test } = obj;

  () => testFunc(obj.test); // error (why does this not work?)
  () => testFunc(test); // works 
}

function testFunc(testString: string) {
  return testString;
}
```

1. I create an object (obj) with an optional value "test".
2. I check the optional value in an if.

Destructuring works, but not if you use the object and value right away.

Comment: Consider `delete obj.test` running at some point after the `if` but before `() => testFunc(obj.test)` executes. What would be the value passed into `testFunc`? What would be the value when you use `() => testFunc(test)` instead?

Answer (score 4):

An attribute with `?` (like test in `IObj`) has the possibility of being undefined, so the type of `test` is `string | undefined`.

When you check for the existence of the `test` attribute in your if statement, you are explicitly saying that `test` must not be undefined to enter the block. Accessing `obj.test` or your newly created variable `test` should return a string.

However, the problem is that you are using `obj.test` inside an *arrow function*, which creates a new scope and loses the validation you did earlier. Basically, for typescript, there's no way to guarantee that `obj.test` won't be undefined when the function is called.

This problem does not occur with the `test` variable because when you create it inside the if statement, the `obj.test` is a `string`, so test is also a `string`, with no possibility of `undefined`.

Consider the following example:

```
if (obj.test) {
  const { test } = obj;

  setTimeout(() => {
    testFunc(obj.test);
    testFunc(test);
  }, 5000);

  obj.test = undefined;
}
```

`setTimeout` also creates another scope and, as you might know, it will execute the function after `X` milliseconds (5 seconds in this case). Since it's not blocking, the flow of execution will reach `obj.test = undefined` *before* `testFunc(obj.test)` within `setTimeout`. This is an example of a problem that can occur.

Comment: The `setTimeout` is slightly superfluous. Also, the fact it creates a new scope is prety much irrelevant. A simple way to demonstrate the problem is to just modify `obj.test` before calling the functions: https://tsplay.dev/w6LGym

Comment: @VLAZ I liked your example too, it's another way to demonstrate the problem. But i think that the fact it creates a new scope is very relevant for this question and it is very explicitly in your example too. The `setTimeout` is just a more 'didactic' example.

Answer (score 0):

Since typescript 4.9 you can use the new [satisfies operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) instead of the type-assertion:

```js
interface IObj {
  test?: string;
}

const obj = {
  test: "why does this not work?",
} satisfies IObj;

if (obj.test) {
  const { test } = obj;

  () => testFunc(obj.test); // works
  () => testFunc(test); // works 
}

function testFunc(testString: string) {
    console.log(testString);
  return testString;
}
```

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkBGArZBvAKGWUgGcwB%20ALmXKlAHMBuAgXwIIQHsRzkucyALz4iJCORoAiAO4ALAJ7IAJlwkk5wUshBcwyGVygBrClIA0bWnDBaYwdRhwsCwGMgAUA7ADoyYAEpRYm5efTxxPlZhfmcOYg8goQA%20SLAAMQBXEAQvHD8JQKZkAHoSgyNjUjFE4VT-LJyPfwDisoqTbTYOGGyEWx40xtz-AGUwehAGGjpGIMJiEJ5SLgAbCB9VrgZmwvHJhlaxKAgwTKgQNP3GFlYgA)